# Which equivalence class represents the zero element $0_{\mathbb Q}$ in $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

**The Statement of the Problem:**

We identify $\mathbb Q$ with the set of equivalence classes $[a,b]$, where $(a,b) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb N^+$ and $(a,b) \sim (a'b')$ iff $ab'=ba'$. We define $(a,b) \ge (c,d)$ iff $ad \ge bc$.

i) Show that this relation is well defined on the quotient, i.e. if $(a,b) \sim (a',b')$ and $(c,d) \sim (c',d')$ then $(a,b) \ge (c,d)$ iff $(a',b') \ge (c',d')$.

ii) Which equivalence class represents the zero element $0_{\mathbb Q}$ in $\mathbb Q$? Which elements in $\mathbb Q$ are less than or equal to $0_{\mathbb Q}$?

**Where I Am:**

So, I'm pretty sure I got part (i), but I don't really understand part (ii). (I included the first part just for context.) Wouldn't it just be when $a$ or $b$ equals $0$ because then you'd have multiplication by $0$? That doesn't seem right to me. If anyone could steer me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Try to think what these equivalence classes represent. What are these pairs of numbers? I we pretended they "were" rational numbers, what are $(a, b)$ in terms of the fraction $p/q$?

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean. As in if $(p,q) \sim (p',q')$ then $pq'=p'q$, so, in a sense, $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{p'}{q'}$. Is that it?

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude Exactly. And now, represent $0_{\Bbb{Q}}=\frac{0}{1}$

Comment: Or even by $0/2, 0/3, \ldots$. Really, you end up with $0 = \{(0, n) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The question can be translated into: what equivalence class is the neutral element under addition? That is, describe $0_\mathbb{Q}=[a_0,b_0]$ such that for any $[a,b]\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have:
$$[a_0,b_0]+[a,b]=[a,b].$$
I think you can take it from here.

Comment: This may depend on whether or not they have defined addition on these equivalence classes yet...

Comment: @SimonRose Sure, but if they don't have any addition then it doesn't make sense to speak of the "zero element"...